# a finite real-valued measurable function $f$ in $E$ such that $f$ is not continuous relative to $E-Z$ for any $Z$ with $|Z|=0$

Tags: real-analysis

On $\mathbb{R}^n$, find a measurable subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a finite, real-valued, measurable function $f$ on $E$ such that $f$ is not continuous relative to $E-Z$ for any $Z$ with $|Z|=0$.

I have no idea how to start it. Is there anyone who can give me some hint or direction?

Thanks for considering my request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by $|Z|=0$, you mean that the measure of $Z$ is 0. In that case do the following.

Take a fat Cantor set. I.e., a Cantor set of positive measure, $K$. Let $E=[0,1]$, and let $f=1_K$, the indicator function of the Cantor set. Now if we remove a set $Z$ with zero measure, there must still be some point left in $K$, and from the construction of the Cantor set, every open ball around $x$ contains some open interval in the complement of $K$, which has positive measure, hence contains a point of $E-Z$. Thus $x$ is a limit of points $y_n$ in $E-Z$ that are not in $K$, but $f(x)=1$, and $f(y_n)=0$, so $f$ cannot be continuous at $x$. Hence $f$ is not continuous on $E-Z$ for any set $Z$ of measure 0.